# Using SNMP to obtain server information

Tags: networking, network-programming, snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j

I need to obtain information about my servers running on Linux Redhat, Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008. I have found the SNMP protocol to be useful for my purpose, but I am not clear how to implement it in my application. I don't even know how to get started.

Also, is it possible to monitor the applications/programs running on the servers? It is my first time working with SNMP, so I am finding it extremely difficult to understand how it has to be implemented. I have understood the architecture of SNMP(SNMPManager, SNMPAgent, Trap messages, MIB), but finding it difficult to implement them.

Please guide me in as detailed way as possible and mention links to any tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

**SNMP** is not so simple as *should be*... if you want to provide control to your system/resources the best choice is to use an external native tool like:

- [PRTG](https://www.paessler.com/prtg):You can use free evaluation sensor
- [CACTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacti_(software)): open-source and web-based tool
- [SolarWinds](http://www.solarwinds.com/):expensive but powerful choice

  After that you can monitor your system using WMI protocol (for Win OS), direct agent installed on it or script.